# Can I say eight-gon, nine-gon and ten-gon instead of octa-, nona-, and deca-gon?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, numbers, mathematics

As a non-native English speaker I struggle with Greek prefixes. Am I allowed to use just normal English numbers in place of them? Is it natural? Or do I have to learn how those Greek prefixes work at the end of the day?

Comment: I've never heard these, but I think I would understand them if I heard them.

Comment: @ColinFine up to how many Greek prefixes do you know?

Comment: You would call it an eight-sided polygon. Not eight-gon. And you could do that in a great many languages not just English. But maybe more to the point, you could also just say *octagon* in all these languages. So if you just learn that, you actually save yourself work in the end because everyone will understand you from New York to Paris to Berlin to Moscow. And also, those prefixes are incredibly useful for other things and pop up in all kinds of other places. Octopus, octave, October. Decade, decimal, December. You will end up learning all of them anyway. You already have.

Comment: A corollary of that is that if you do go with *eight-gon* and *ten-gon*, people won't take that to mean you're trying to make things easy for yourself. They wiill take that to mean you're trying to be difficult on purpose. Because everyone knows about the decade and the octopus. And everyone can draw the connection.

Comment: In the US, at least, you can say pretty much anything you want -- you (probably) won't be shot for it.  The terms you suggest would be generally understood, and I think they are quite acceptable coming from someone who clearly has an incomplete command of the language.  If, however, you will be talking in an academic environment you probably should take the effort to learn the correct terms.  (Personally, I kind of detest the ordinals -- I think they should be "wonth", "tooth", "threeth", "forth", and "fifeth".)

Comment: @RegDwigнt wouldn't be so sure about Moscow. We have Russian names for the polygons, so "Pentagon" would probably be associated with the US Armed Forces HQ, and the rest would be meaningful only to mathematicians.

Comment: @RegDwigнt "Octopus, octave, October. Decade, decimal, December." It perhaps confuses the issue given that October and December are the 10th and 12th months, respectively.

Comment: @josh314 it doesn't confuse the issue, quite the opposite. It makes you wonder, okay, so why the heck *is* the 12th month called the tenth? And the 9th month called the seventh? And that makes you research it, and you find out something new and exciting. And you've learned something else completely for free, just because you refused to say *ten-gon*. Isn't that wonderful.

Comment: Why even call them '-gons' if you want to avoid greek?

Comment: Why not just say eight sided, nine sided, ten sided if you want to avoid Greek?

Comment: @josh314 Because they _were_ the 8th and 10th months when they were so named.

Comment: I enjoy confusing my fellow mathematicians even further. Why call it a triangle when you can call it a trigon?  Why call it a quadrilateral when you can it a tetragon? Oh, its so fun... and the distinction between when to use gon and when to use lateral, when use greek prefixes and when to use latin prefixes.... you just learned something new again.

Comment: To be fair, laymen and mathematicians both use terms like 255-gon. Ive seen it in texts and in papers. Ive seen it in lecture halls.  No one can dare tell me that speakers of other languages wouldnt understand the "255" that precedes the "gon", at least in writing. Its easier and more comprehensible than saying dihectapentacontakaipentagon. But hey, thats just my two cents.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Mathematicians do use this form for bigger numbers. The Wikipedia article [Heptadecagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecagon) currently contains the phrase "a regular 51-gon, 85-gon or 255-gon and any regular n-gon with 2<sup>h</sup> times as many sides".

And in that context, you may find mathematicians using the form for smaller numbers: in an article about polygons of different sizes, I would not be surprised to meet "5-gon" or "8-gon".

But outside mathematics, I've never heard anybody say "eight-gon" or any of the others.

Comment: I would distinguish between "8-gon" and "eight-gon" here. When using a number, it can be considered as a substitution of the "n".  "Eight-gon", however, would imply that this is a defined English word. This is similar to "with 2h times" where both 2 and h are used in a mathematical, not linguistic, sense.

Comment: I find it so weird that in English the decimal values are inversed. In Greek, we say deca-hepta-gon (which is the normal to call 17). But maybe that's because in English, the numbers 13-19 are named inversely (four-teen). Now that I think of it, 11-12 or also named inversely in Greek (en-deca, do-deca).

Comment: Colin, have you heard "eight-gon" spoken in a mathematics sense? My understanding is (similar to @Flater's) that "8-gon" would be proncounced "octagon" and the use of "*number*-gon" in speech would kick in when the speaker doesn't know or can't be bothered to work out the prefix.  But I'm not an expert

Comment: No. @ChrisH, I don't think I've ever discussed such things in person! I'm not sure what I would say.

Comment: Anybody using a greek prefix for a 27-gon is a clasically educated show-off! In written English outside the realm of mathematics I'd write 27-sided polygon (27-gon) and then use the abbreviation introduced in the brackets and the obvious generalization thereof.  In speech I'd similarly make the usage clear the first time I used it.

Comment: Prefixes that any native speaker of English can be expected to know without clarification are tri- quad- penta- hexa- (maybe hepta-) octa- and deca-

Comment: @bill-kotsias it's also old or poetic English usage. A well known nursery rhyme: "four-and-twenty blackbirds baked in a pie ..." I'd guess that the language got regularized when Arabic numerals read from left to right took over from Latin numerals which needed complex decoding (MCMDLXIV ...)

Comment: @nigel222 in this context *dodeca-* shouyld probably be included, but apart form that I agree

Comment: @nigel222: still current in German: _einundzwanzig_.

Comment: I had a high-school teacher (mid 1980s, midwest U.S.) who absolutely did say things like "eleven-agon" and "27-agon" and so on.  I knew, and I believe most of the class knew, he was being partly facetious and this use non-standard.  But we also got the point he was making.

Comment: @ChrisH I have definitely heard people pronounce the number in "17-gon", although it would still be written with numerals. I would expect most mathematicians to do this for 13-gon and above, although I'm not sure I have any evidence (either way) except for 17. Partly this is influenced by the fact that a mathematician would very easily talk about an *n*-gon, where there is no real alternative. But for smaller numbers (other than perhaps 11) it would sound very strange not to use the Greek prefix.

Comment: @ChrisH polygons with large numbers of sides do have some mathematical interest (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon) but I've never heard a mathematician call a 17-gon called anything except a "seventeen-gon".

Comment: @ChrisH And, at least when used for [Platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid) instead of plane figures, _icosa-_.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime "17-gon" would certainly cross the line and count as doesn't know/couldn't be bothered -- even if the speaker knows it would be unwise to assume the audience does. It sounds like we're in agreement actually, even if the phrasing of my previous comment could hae been clearer

Comment: @alephzero This takes me back to a school problem - something to do with the area bounded by an *n*-gon of fixed perimeter as *n* → ∞.  I can't remember whether we used this term, or something more cumbersome.

Comment: @nigel222 That particular rhyme calls for a pair of [trochees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochee), and "twenty-four" isn't such a pair. It has little or nothing to do with a switch from Roman numerals to Arabic numerals.

Comment: @ChrisH As a mathematician I can attest that 8-gon is not pronounced "octagon." It's pronounced "eight-gon."

Answer (score 19):

Short answer: **no**.

Longer answer: you will probably be understood, but people will think it's strange. Almost all words in English have roots in other languages. For these words, you have correctly identified Greek as the original language. Curiously, you have taken exception with the prefixes, but not the suffix: *-gon*, which is also Greek.

As a more interesting case, *triangle* uses the *-angle* suffix, which comes from Latin.
<sub>*(* tri- *is both a Greek and Latin prefix.)*</sub>

---

Personal note:
In my travels as a mathematician, I admit that I have heard and used *n-gon* a lot. When a mathematical discussion involved specific instances of an *n-gon*, it was sometimes most natural to say things like *eight-gon*; especially when other, higher *-gon* were included in the discussion. Outside of the context of pure maths, it would be extremely unusual for anyone, even a mathematician, to say *eight-gon*.

Comment: I wouldn't say "almost all" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_words_by_country_or_language_of_origin

Comment: And while less common than *quadrilateral* (literally meaning "four-sided"), *quadrangle* is perfectly valid for a 4-gon.

Comment: @BenVoigt The bygone tetragon.

Comment: @AzorAhai "Almost all" is right by count in a dictionary, but not by usage.  Search for "Uncleftish beholding" to see what English would look like without foreign words.

Comment: +1. Note that you could explain the word when you use it for the first time, e.g. "an enneagon (nine-sided polygon)".

Comment: @Rosie Isn't it interesting that the more common term for a 9-sided polygon is _nonagon_, which uses a Latin prefix with a Greek suffix?

Answer (score 10):

> Am I allowed to use just normal English numbers in place of them?

No. There is no such word as eightgon.

> Is it natural?

No. If I heard "eightgon" I would think I heard "eight gone" or "ate gone". You can't just make up words like that.

---

You may as well replace "triangle" with "threegon", or "rectangle" with "fourgon".  No-one will understand you, and the purpose of language is to be understood.

Comment: Yes, thank you for this answer.  I would also be confused and not immediately make the connection that the OP wants me to make.  Also, "fourgon" is homophonous with an existing word, "forgone", so that would definitely be confusing

Comment: @NickGammon _You may as well replace "triangle" with "threegon", or "rectangle" with "fourgon". No-one will understand you, and the purpose of language is to be understood._ And everyone will understand me if I say Tetracontagon? I don't think so.

Comment: For kicks, here are an illustrated two-gon - and one-gon .

Comment: @Beanluc now show us the zero-gon

Comment: I did, I just didn't mention it, but here it is again

Comment: @Happy *And everyone will understand me if I say Tetracontagon?* Indeed not, however Tetracontagon was not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 7):

"Octagon" and "hexagon" are well established and "common" English words because of the corresponding shapes occur frequently in nature (honeycombs, crystals, etc) and in architecture.

"Pentagon" is commonly used as shorthand for the US Department of Defense (from the shape of its headquarters building).

"Heptagon" is not so common, but it is used to describe the shape of the UK 50 pence and 20 pence coins - though amusingly, one coin dealer has invented the adjective "heptagonical" instead of the standard "heptagonal"! (ref: https://www.westminstercollection.com/p-201P/UK-50-New-PenceCirculation-50p.aspx).

For more than 8 sides, the usual British English terminology is simply "[number]-sided," though decagon and even more rarely dodecagon (the shape of the new UK £1 coin) are used.

Even "three-sided" and "four-sided" are often used in non-mathematical contexts, especially when the object being described is not a regular shape like a square or rectangle. Using "eight-sided" instead of "octagonal" would not sound strange in most non-technical contexts.

Note that for "four-", both Latin and Greek prefixes are used in English - quadrilateral, quadriceps, etc (Latin), and tetrahedron, tetraplegic, etc (Greek). The same applies to "bi-" (Latin) and "di-" (Greek) for "two-".

Comment: Nice answer. Interestingly, heptagon and decagon are used about equally in modern times ([post-1950](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heptagon%2Cnonagon%2Cdecagon%2Cdodecagon%2Cnine-sided&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheptagon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnonagon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecagon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdodecagon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnine%20-%20sided%3B%2Cc0)) while dodecagon and nonagon are only about a third as common - but nonagon is still twice as popular as *nine-sided*!

Comment: @Chappo I suspect nonagons are rare enough that you'd mostly find them in mathematical contexts, where people are more likely to know the proper prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Older Germanic languages had very few nouns and adjectives to describe geometric shapes. English had native words for a circle, [*trendel*](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/finder/3/trendel) and [*hring*](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/finder/3/hring), an arch [*boga*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bow#etymonline_v_15679), cf. Ger. *Bogen*, and words for three- and four-cornered, [_ þriscíte_](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/032101) and, variously spelled, [*feoðerscéte , feðerscíte , fiðerscýte , fyðerscýte*](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/finder/3/scite).

[*Square*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/square#etymonline_v_21931), from Old French *esquire*, first entered English as a carpenter’s square mid 13th c., a square shape/area in the late 14th c., and finally as a rectangle with equal sides in the 1550s. This would suggest that a carpenter couldn’t use a square to draw the eponymous shape for well over a century.

[*Triangle*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/triangle) was borrowed directly from French in the late 13th c.

The most common names for polygons, with 5–8 sides, entered English from Greek via Latin [in the 1560s](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pentagon#etymonline_v_12639). This tells you a great deal about the systematic study of geometry in England as *pentagonon* and *octagonon* lost their endings to become what we call them today. You’re basically stuck with them. Such bizarre grecogermanic hybrids like **five-gon* do not exist.

Other Germanic languages went through a similar process, but the names of polygons were calqued into native words: Ger. *Dreieck*, lit. ‘three-corner’, just as Old English, but as nouns, *Viereck, Achteck*, etc. Cf. Dutch *driehoek*, Danish and Norwegian *trekant* (same meaning, different root), but Swedish *triangel*.

The Greek and Latin cardinal and ordinal numbers pop up in so many English and international words that it pays to learn them, *sextuplets, quad bike, bicycle, tricycle, mononucleosis,* and on and on.

Comment: I should add that to my ear ‘85-angle’ (by analogy with ‘triangle’ sounds better and makes easier sense.

Comment: @Tuffy Strange, "85-angle" makes me think of a 85° angle first and foremost, especially if I were to see it in writing.

Answer (score 0):

> As a non-native English speaker I struggle with Greek prefixes.

Nothing that can't be remedied with few hours of study.

> Am I allowed to use just normal English numbers in place of them?

Who is your audience, if you are talking to another  math person then
are you using them for uniformity/clarity or just to cover your own lack of understanding of few prefixes?

Does pi-gon or zero-gon or (-3)-gon make sense to you? how about 0,1,2, n , 2*n gons?

You can invoke decree of creative license and get away with it, as long as you are adding to the total sum of knowledge and not doing it to cover lack of your own understanding.

> Is it natural? Or do I have to learn how those Greek prefixes work at
>   the end of the day?

Do you think a professional in their chosen profession is suppose to know the common vocabulary of their field?

This question has nothing to do with usage of English language but all to do with going the extra mile of being a professional, so to sum it up

For sake clarity/uniformity/communication and depending on the target audience yes. But just to not learn something then no.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can as long as you are consistent, "gon" is greek and should be replaced too with "side shape".
So hexagon gets replaced with "six side shape". You'll soon find learning the greek prefixes more convenient.